# How would you integrate numerically this function?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

How do you understand this integral ignoring the rect function?
dx and dz are the pixel size of the numerical grid.

[image]

Comment: The square bracket there is probably the [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) which is $1$ if the condition insider the bracket is satisfied and $0$ otherwise. For your case, it means only integrate over those region which falls inside the intersection of the disk $x^2 + (z-1500)^2 \le 600^2$ and the half-plane $z < 1800$.

Comment: Thank you. Then probably integral is not needed.